# Is there a nice way to handle "invalid hexadecimal digits" when using DECODE?

Tags: postgresql

How can I check the value here before getting an error? Or how can I suppress the ERROR? Or just get NULL?

```
postgres=# SELECT DECODE('166D24ABBEDR', 'hex');
ERROR:  invalid hexadecimal digit: "R"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `CASE` expression and the `translate` function:

```
CASE
   WHEN translate(x, '0123456789abcdefABCDEF', '') = ''
   THEN decode(x, 'hex')
   ELSE NULL
END
```

Comment: I have it in a WHERE clause of a SELECT and finally did this: `DECODE(NULLIF(COALESCE(NULLIF(('2ffc' ~ '^[0-9a-fA-F]+$')::text, 'true'), '2ffc'), 'false'), 'hex');`

Comment: If you like, sure. But regular expressions are more expensive than `translate`.

Comment: I'm using it for 64 bytes long public keys and here using a regex is not slower. Still, thank you!